how to pass q_auto:good into my URL based Cloudinary Component
I have a Component in my app that is uploadFiles.js and for Optimization I want to use the q_auto:good parameter into my current component. I tried different approaches but I did not see any difference between the file size before and after the upload.
here is my current component.
Note: I use URL not NPM package
async function uploadFiles(savedImages, input) {
  let files = input.files;
  let filesUrls = [];
  let i = savedImages?.length > 0 ? savedImages?.length : 0;

  for (const file of files) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("upload_preset", <upload_preset_ID>);
    let response = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudinary_name>/image/upload",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      }
    );

    await response.json().then((data) => {
      i++;
      filesUrls.push({ imageFilePath: data.secure_url, imageOrder: i });
    });
  }

  return savedImages ? [...savedImages, ...filesUrls] : [...filesUrls];
}

export { uploadFiles };


I try to pass the q_auto:good on the URL and Got 404 Error
I try to append the formData and it show me the value into Payload but did not find any change
here is my current optimization settings on Cloudinary. Does it ok?

To optimize image quality with q_auto:good in Cloudinary, apply it when generating URLs for image access, not during upload. Adjust your function to append ?q_auto:good to the URLs after upload:
await response.json().then((data) => {
  i++;
  const optimizedUrl = `${data.secure_url}?q_auto:good`;
  filesUrls.push({ imageFilePath: optimizedUrl, imageOrder: i });
});


